# Why SQL NOT IN() operator not working?

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql statement and I want to fetch data from **users**  table where user id is NOT in another table of column_one and column_two.

I dont know why this statement return an error:

**This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'**

So with this error I remove the LIMIT statement and now it says :

**Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

I can see SQL wants me to select only one column in the sub-query but this is not what I want.

How can I make it work avoiding all these errors and return a valid sql statement with my filtering?

This is the SQL code I tried:

```
SELECT u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname,u.id,u.school
        FROM users u
            WHERE u.id NOT IN(
                SELECT user_two,user_one FROM friends 
                    WHERE user_one !='8' 
                        OR user_two  !='8'
            )
```

Comment: change it to           AND user_two

Comment: It worked !...but I need explanation....I have used the AND filtering but not like this. can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically You have an asimmetric use of IN operator

the two part of the in clause must contain the same number of component

You  should use

```
SELECT u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname,u.id,u.school
    FROM users u
        WHERE u.id NOT IN( 
            SELECT  id  FROM friends 
                WHERE user_one !='8' 
                    OR user_two  !='8'
        )
```

or

```
SELECT u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname,u.id,u.school
    FROM users u
        WHERE (u.id1, u.id2) NOT IN( 
            SELECT  user_two,user_one  FROM friends 
                WHERE user_one !='8' 
                    OR user_two  !='8'
        )
```

or the result is impredictable